# Generate RSA signature using public key

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to generate a RSA signature using a public key that is provided to me from the backend dev. But I am not able to sign without the private key. When I ask the backend dev, he says that I should be able to generate signature with the public key only! I am getting confused now. Here is my dart code using [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) package.

On running the code, it throws an error => 'Can't sign without a private key, null given.'

How do I generate signature using public key only ??

```
String? _generateSignature({
    required final String data,
    required final String publicKey,
}) {
    final parsedPublicKey = RSAKeyParser().parse(publicKey);

    if (parsedPublicKey is RSAPublicKey) {
      final signer = Signer(
        RSASigner(
          RSASignDigest.SHA256,
          publicKey: parsedPublicKey,
        ),
      );
      final signature = signer.sign(data).base64;
      return signature;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: By definition of asymmetric cryptography, signing is done with a private key. I'm afraid, your backend dev is terribly wrong. I mean, if you can sign with a public key, everybody can, because it is, you know, public.

Comment: You seem to confuse encryption and signing. Encryption is done with the public key, signing with the private key.

Comment: This is impossible to generate signatures using a public key only.